# Placement new based on template sizeof()

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, signals, placement-new

Is this legal in c++11?  Compiles with the latest intel compiler and appears to work, but I just get that feeling that it is a fluke.

```
 class cbase
        {
        virtual void call();
        };

template<typename T> class functor : public cbase
    {
    public:
        functor(T* obj, void (T::*pfunc)())
            : _obj(obj), _pfunc(pfunc) {}

        virtual void call()
            {
            (_obj)(*_pfunc)();
            }
    private:
        T& _obj;
        void (T::*_pfunc)();            
        //edited: this is no good:
        //const static int size = sizeof(_obj) + sizeof(_pfunc);
    };

class signal
    {
    public:
        template<typename T> void connect(T& obj, void (T::*pfunc)())
            {
            _ptr = new (space) functor<T>(obj, pfunc);
            }
    private:
        cbase* _ptr;
        class _generic_object {};
        typename aligned_storage<sizeof(functor<_generic_object>), 
            alignment_of<functor<_generic_object>>::value>::type space;
        //edited: this is no good:
        //void* space[(c1<_generic_object>::size / sizeof(void*))];

    };
```

Specifically I'm wondering if `void* space[(c1<_generic_object>::size / sizeof(void*))];` is really going to give the correct size for c1's member objects (_obj and _pfunc).  (It isn't).

EDIT:
So after some more research it would seem that the following would be (more?) correct:

```
typename aligned_storage<sizeof(c1<_generic_object>), 
    alignment_of<c1<_generic_object>>::value>::type space;
```

However upon inspecting the generated assembly, using placement new with this space seems to inhibit the compiler from optimizing away the call to 'new' (which seemed to happen while using just regular '_ptr = new c1;'

EDIT2: Changed the code to make intentions a little clearer.

Comment: How is that even supposed to compile without providing an initializer for a reference member in `c1`? Is there any specific importance in that reference member or not?

Comment: Also, what is the idea behind calculating memory size through `sizeof(_obj)`, which evaluates to the size of full object (i.e. `sizeof T`), yet later construct a `c1<some_type_t>` object in that place, which will physically contain only a *reference* to `some_type_t` (implemented as a pointer)?

Comment: I don't know if it compiles or not, it's a very simplified example I made to post here to cut to the relevant parts.  I'm writing a signal/callback class and wish to eliminate dynamic memory allocation if possible.

Comment: Well, at this point the code does not seem to make any sense. Could it be that you accidentally removed something important?

Comment: I changed the names a bit and added a little, hopefully it makes (more) sense now.

Comment: isn't `_obj(obj)` supposed to be `_obj(*obj)`?

Answer (score 3):

`const static int size = sizeof(_obj) + sizeof(_pfunc);` will give the sum of the sizes of the members, but that may not be the same as the size of the class containing those members. The compiler is free to insert padding between members or after the last member. As such, adding together the sizes of the members approximates the smallest that object could possibly be, but doesn't necessarily give the size of an object with those members.

In fact, the size of an object can vary depending not only on the types of its members, but also on their order. For example:

```
struct A { 
    int a;
    char b;
};
```

vs:

```
struct B { 
    char b;
    int a;
};
```

In many cases, `A` will be smaller than `B`. In `A`, there will typically be no padding between `a` and `b`, but in `B`, there will often be some padding (e.g., with a 4-byte int, there will often be 3 bytes of padding between `b` and `a`).

As such, your `space` may not contain enough...space to hold the object you're trying to create there in `init`.

Comment: That's a good point.  Ideally I could store the objects directly in c2, but since I don't know T until a member function is called, I can't do that it seems.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just got lucky; Jerry's answer points out that there may be padding issues. What I think you have is a non-virtual class (i.e., no vtable), with essentially two pointers (under the hood).

That aside, the arithmetic: `(c1<_generic_object>::size / sizeof(void*))` is flawed because it will truncate if `size` is *not* a multiple of `sizeof(void *)`. You would need something like:

`((c1<_generic_object>::size + sizeof(void *) - 1) / sizeof(void *))`

Answer (score 1):

This code does not even get to padding issues, because it has a few of more immediate ones.

Template class `c1` is defined to contain a member `T &_obj` of reference type. Applying `sizeof` to `_obj` in scope of `c1` will evaluate to the size of `T`, not to the size of reference member itself. It is not possible to obtain the physical size of a reference in C++ (at least directly). Meanwhile, any actual object of type `c1<T>` will physically contain a reference to `T`, which is typically implemented in such cases as a pointer "under the hood".

For this reason it is completely unclear to me why the value of `c1<_generic_object>::size` is used as a measure of memory required for in-pace construction of an actual object of type `c1<T>` (for any `T`). It just doesn't make any sense. These sizes are not related at all.

By pure luck the size of an empty class `_generic_object` might evaluate to the same (or greater) value as the size of a physical implementation of a reference member. In that case the code will allocate a sufficient amount of memory. One might even claim that the `sizeof(_generic_object) == sizeof(void *)` equality will "usually" hold in practice. But that would be just a completely arbitrary coincidence with no meaningful basis whatsoever.

This even looks like red herring deliberately inserted into the code for the purpose of pure obfuscation.

P.S. In GCC `sizeof` of an empty class actually evaluates to `1`, not to any "aligned" size. Which means that the above technique is guaranteed to initialize `c1<_generic_object>::size` with a value that is too small. More specifically, in 32 bit GCC the value of `c1<_generic_object>::size` will be `9`, while the actual size of any `c1<some_type_t>` will be `12` bytes.